# Merging dlls from dlls working under licensing

Tags: c#, dll, merge

I will appreciate your help in this. I have spent many time in looking for a procedure or tool that can let me create a single DLL from other private dlls (I named private because these dlls are working under licensing). I already bought the lic but I dont like to see the vendors name in my apps (I'd prefer to see the dlls as MyDll.dll rather than Microsoft.dll)

I have used the Gilma and the ILMerger tool that Microsoft has in its website without results. So do you guys know how to create this dll?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

Tools like ILMerge will merge managed assemblies. However, you may have problems doing this with 3rd party dlls as they will most likely be code-signed with a certificate and obfuscated to stop people tampering with them in any way.

Another approach would be to embed the 3rd party dlls as file Resources. You can then load them with Assembly.Load using a Stream created directly from your resources (GetManifestResourceStream), so the user will never see them as separate files on disk, but you won't actually be attempting to change their contents.